# how to set a fiexd hostname for azure container app service

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify a fixed hostname for an azure container app service? Just like what we did using the command "docker run --name xxx -h {fixed-hostname} ...", thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter the Azure Container Instance or the Azure Web App for Container, they both do not support to change the containers' hostname, the hostname is set by Azure.